# Get a list of open documents in Qt Creator

Tags: qt-creator

Is there a way to get a list of open documents in Qt Creator.

Sometimes when Qt Creator crashes and is unable to restore the session when reopened, its handy to have a list of open files before it crashed.

Comment: hi - if you by chance got an answer to that - please share

Comment: @yatsek, No I haven't figured out an answer for this yet.

Answer (score 4):

Not sure if this is what you are looking for, but using QtCreator 4.15.2, from the "Projects" pane (default left panel), there is an option to "Split" (4th icon) with a selection for "Open Documents".  This then creates a panel (below) that shows the open documents.

Answer (score -2):

Why do you need that list?

Conceptionally *all* files in for project are open once you open the project. The open document list is just a history of recently visited documents.

I find it way simpler to just jump to the classes/methods/files/lines/help I care for (using ctrl-K -- if you are not using that key combo, you are missing the best thing in creator!). That way I do not need to keep remembering what is in which files.

Comment: Sometimes, Qt just crashes. When I open the project again, I basically lost all the recently opened files. If I had a list of all files, I could manually open all those files.
"Search in all opened files" is a feature that I frequently use.